# How do I pass jQuery value to php?

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I have this little piece of code and I would like to pass the value to PHP.

```
  var size;

  if ($(window).width() < 960) {
      size = "1";
  } else {
      size = "2";
  }
```

Is there a way to do this? (new at jQuery)

Many thanks!

Comment: Use ajax or form submission to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var size;

if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    size = "1";
} else {
    size = "2";
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'edit.php',
    data: "window_size=" + size,
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result)
    }
});
</script>
```

then create edit.php

```
<?php
 print_r($_REQUEST);


 ?>
```

if you want to save this value then use this code

```
<?php
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['php_value'];
 ?>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 var size;

if ($(window).width() < 960) {
size = "1";
} else {
size = "2";
}
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'edit.php',
data: "window_size=" + size,
dataType: 'text',
async: false,
cache: false,
success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
    //window.location.reload();

}
});
</script>
```

and update edit.php as like

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['php_value'] = $_REQUEST['window_size'];
echo $_SESSION['php_value'];
?>
```

you want to see this value or use then refresh this page
if you want to use this variable in other page then use this

```
//first page first set it 
 $_SESSION['php_value'] = $_REQUEST['window_size'];

//second page or other page and use it
 $var_value = $_SESSION['php_value'];
```

Comment: thats nice, but how do i save this in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. JQuery plays on client and php on backend.

If you want to pass some values from Client (Jquery/Js) to Backend (PHP), you need to either submit a form or make an AJax call to server.

Answer (score 0):

You should research about [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). This can be your solution for sending data to server from client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the code below to send the value of size to your php script:

```
var ajax_call = $.ajax({url: '/your_php_script.php', data: 'size='+size, success: function(data) {          

}});
```