# jQuery Pass Multiple Checkbox Value to PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have jQuery to get multiple checkbox value.

You can refer for the demo [here](https://jsbin.com/cosebiqilo/edit?html,output)

The function for that jQuery is OK, when We tick the checkbox then We can see what We choose based on data-id after btnUpdate click.

But now I want to pass and store it to database using PHP by Ajax.
So Example output,

```
1 -> read
1 -> update
2 -> update
```

Then save it to database on table:

```
ID | chkStatus
1  | read
1  | update
2  | update
```

Here is the HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Nama</th>
  <th>Create</th>
  <th>Read</th>
  <th>Update</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>coba</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="1" data-tipe="create"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="1" data-tipe="read"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="1" data-tipe="update"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="1" data-tipe="delete"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>coba 2</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="create"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="read"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="update"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="delete"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" id="btnUpdate" value="Update"/>
</tr>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnUpdate').click(function(){
    var cb = [];
    $.each($('input[type=checkbox]:checked'), function(){
      cb.push($(this).data('id') + ' -> ' +$(this).data('tipe'));
    });
    $('#status').val(cb.join("\n"));
  })
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530480/how-do-i-pass-jquery-value-to-php/42531178#42531178

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can send arrays server side via both get or post, in your case here I'd recommend modifying how you're building the array mind:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnUpdate').click(function(){
        var cb = [],
            post_cb = []

        $.each($('input[type=checkbox]:checked'), function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id'),
                tipe = $(this).data('tipe')

            cb.push(id + ' -> ' + tipe);
            post_cb.push({
                'id': id,
                'tipe': tipe
            });
        });
        $('#status').val(cb.join("\n"));

        $.ajax({
            'type': 'post',
            'url': '/path/to/script.php',
            'data': {
                'cb': post_cb
            },
            'success': function(response) {
                // Do something
            },
            'error': function(response) {
                // Do something
            }
        });
    })
});
```

And then in your PHP file:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST['cb']);
/*

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [tipe] => read
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [tipe] => update
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [tipe] => update
        )

)

*/

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how to store it to database? if I have table column: ID | CHKVALUE

Comment: What database technology are you using? MySQL? I'm asking because depending on the database, the PHP functions you use will be different

Comment: Hi Scoots, I'm using Oracle DB

Comment: Hey again, sorry for the delay in replying to this. I'm afraid I have no experience working with Oracle DB and as such am uncomfortable writing out sample code for you. However, I can point you at the relevant PHP docs, which have a few examples of common queries: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php